# Issues with Inserting uneven data from datagridview into database c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi i have this codes that insert data from datagridview to database

```
for (int i = 0; i < ADODB.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(@Team, @SIC, @EID,@EmployeeName,@Username,@Password,@Designation,@Department,@Email,@HireDate,@TakenAL,@Status)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SIC", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HireDate", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TakenAL", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

I would like to ask what if i have 12 columns in my datagridview but my database has 13 columns. It would prompt an error due to the the difference in things that are added. How do i solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use autogenerateColumns to be false

Comment: for the datagridview or the database?

Comment: Make your data base column as nullable type or pass empty value from your code.

Comment: Use column names explicitly in the `INSERT` statement, `INSERT INTO Employee (Team, SIC, EID ...) VALUES (@Team, @SIC, @EID...)` then you datagridview will be always correct

Answer (score 0):

Use name reference for the columns, i.e.

```
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells["Team"].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SIC", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells["SIC"].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", ADODB.Rows[i].Cells["EID"].Value);
```

The columns will receive their name from the database column, when you load data from database. Other way is to set and name the columns via GUI in VS, or via code, i.e.:

```
DataGridView1.Column[2].Name = "EID"
```

If you design your column scheme of datagridview in GUI or code first, make sure you use

```
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
```

and that your use that name reference when loading data, using DataPropertyName:

```
DataGridView1.Column[2].DataPropertyName = "EID"
```